# AngularJS: Browser ignores my Controller Definition (Dependency Injection)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate in my project but I am unable to define a controller that has a dependency injection of `$translate`. The code isn't executed in the browser. I checked JSHint already...

`index.html`

```
<html ng-app='ngApp'>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="orderFormCtr">
        <ul>
            <li>{{'TITLE' | translate}}</li>
            <li translate="TITLE"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

// this code works
angular.module('ngApp').config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.translations('en', {
            TITLE: 'Hello'
        });
        $translateProvider.translations('de', {
            TITLE: 'Hallo'
        });
}]);

// the browser ignores this code
angular.module('ngApp').controller('orderFormCtr', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {

    alert("Controller Code executed");

}]);
```

Comment: Does the browser report anything in the JavaScript console? Use Chrome Developer Tools to open a JavaScript console and re-run the application by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

// this code works
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.translations('en', {
            TITLE: 'Hello'
        });
        $translateProvider.translations('de', {
            TITLE: 'Hallo'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
        //or translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage()
}]);

// the browser ignores this code
app.controller('orderFormCtr', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {

    alert("Controller Code executed");

}]);
```

http://jsbin.com/miqazola/1/